# Elements order provided by ConcurrenLinkedtHashmap iterator depends on key size?

Tags: java, guava

I found strange behaviour of (iterator?) ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.
Elements obtained by iterating entrySet/keySet are in strange/unexpected order if key is long. Everything is ok if key is short.

Following code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConcurrentLinkedHashMap<String, String> map =
            new ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.Builder<String, String>().maximumWeightedCapacity(1000).build();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        map.put(i + "", i + "");
    }
    print(map);
    map.clear(); 
    // NOW AGAIN THE SAME, BUT WITH LONG KEY
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        map.put(i + "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" +
                "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" +
                "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", i + "");
    }
    print(map);
}

private static void print(ConcurrentLinkedHashMap<String, String> a) {
    Iterator iterator = a.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(" = " + iterator.next());
    }
}
```

provides such output:

```
 = 0=0
 = 1=1
 = 2=2
 = 3=3
 = 4=4
 = 1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=1
 = 4aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=4
 = 2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=2
 = 3aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=3
 = 0aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=0
```

That is quite strange.
If i make key longer - result is different.

Is it a bug? How could I get correct result?
(second 'print' result should be in the same order as first)

Comment: What version of guava are you using?

Comment: @assylias According to git it has never been a part of Guava, it was just [used as the base](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap) for `MapMaker` and `CacheBuilder`.

Answer (score 5):

> Unlike `java.util.LinkedHashMap`, this class does *not* provide predictable iteration order. 
>   ([Javadoc](http://concurrentlinkedhashmap.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/release-1.3.1-LRU/com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.html))

The documentation is rather clear on that - so no bug

Concerning the order of entries while iterating over them, `ConcurrentLinkedHashMap` provides [ascending](http://concurrentlinkedhashmap.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/release-1.3.1-LRU/com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.html#ascendingKeySet%28%29) and [descending](http://concurrentlinkedhashmap.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/release-1.3.1-LRU/com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.html#descendingKeySet%28%29) order on retention for keys. This might not always be what you are aiming for, but at least for the given test-scenario returns an ordered output given the code below:

```
private static void print(ConcurrentLinkedHashMap<String, String> a)
{
    Iterator iterator = a.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(" = " + iterator.next());
    }
    Iterator<String> iter = a.ascendingKeySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) 
    {
        String key = iter.next();
        System.out.println(key + " -> " + a.get(key));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 = 0=0
 = 1=1
 = 2=2
 = 3=3
 = 4=4
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 3
4 -> 4
 = 1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=1
 = 4aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=4
 = 2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=2
 = 3aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=3
 = 0aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=0
0aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa -> 0
1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa -> 1
2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa -> 2
3aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa -> 3
4aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa -> 4
```

Comment: Well, yes, thanks. Strage why is it called Linked* then.

Comment: @user_x updated my post to include some information regarding `ascendingKeySet`

Comment: @user_x The class provides the `access order = true` feature of LinkedHashMap, which is more commonly needed with multi-threading and difficult to scale. An insertion-order concurrent map is relatively trivial in comparison.